# How can I remove the first 6 characters of the contents of a tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm rendering an RSS feed and there is content at the beginning of each content section - it's always 6 characters and I want to use jQuery to remove it.

The content of the particular bit of feed is in a list tag, so `<li>blahah Hello this is where I want to display from...</li>`

Getting rid of the "**blahah**" is the goal.

**An update:**

The jQuery supplied works great but I can't work out why it's pulling all the list elements as if they're inline!

Would you be able to explain why the li tags in this example - [jsfiddle.net/GhazG/5](http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/5) run into each other when rendered, instead of appearing like this - [jsfiddle.net/GhazG/6](http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/6)?

Comment: Can you post an example feed, showing the context and how it repeats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will remove the first 6 characters for *every* `<li>` element on the page. I imagine you'll want your selector to specifically target the `<li>` in question.

```
   // Select your <li> element
var $li = $('li');

   // Get the text(), and call .substr() passing the number 6 as the argument
   //   indicating that you want to get the part of the string starting on
   //   index number 6 (the seventh character)
$li.text( $li.text().substr(6) );
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/

- http://api.jquery.com/text
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Since you have several `<li>` elements on the page that need updating, you should do so using an `each` loop:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/7/

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.text( $th.text().substr(6) );
});
```

If the items are being appended to the DOM via javascript, you would also have the option of removing the characters *before* you do the append. It would probably be a better approach.

Comment: @jake is correct, though some would consider it to be highly recommended to reference your jQuery objects with variable names that start with `$`. It is a widely used convention and a nice reminder of what the variable references.

Comment: Ahh I've encountered an issue with what I'm trying to do. Would you be able to explain why the li tags in this example - http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/5/ run into each other when rendered, instead of appearing like this - http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/6/?

Thanks!

Comment: @Cordial - Absolutely. :o) You need to perform the action in a loop, so that you are only updating the content of each `<li>` with the current content. I'll update my answer. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GhazG/7/

Comment: fantastic, thanks so much. don't know what i'd do without you people! actually i'd probably be unemployed...